# How to read-in a FOR XML call from a Kamiak Query component in Delphi D6?

Tags: sql, xml, delphi, dataset

Performing an SQL FOR XML RAW statement call with a Kamiak ADO Query component in Delphi6. How to read the returned XML back out of that query component in your code?

Initial problems:

1) There is no "field name" to refer to in the Kamiak components "FieldByName()" method.

2) Attempts to reference the query results as Query.Fields.Fields[0] returns binary that the XMLPartner component can't read-in via their LoadFromMemory( ) method call.

Comment: What did you try? Please share some code.

Comment: While it's great that you want to post a self-answered question, you should be aware that the question still has to meet the same quality guidelines as any other question. This one does not at this point. Please edit to improve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a beautifully simple tweak to the FOR XML RAW statement that made it exceptionally easy to read back out the XML result of the SQL call back out of the kamiak ADO Query component in code.

Essentially take the existing FOR XML RAW select statement, and wrap it up inside the following:

`SELECT CAST((< your FOR XML RAW select stmt goes here >) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS XmlData`

Then... within your Delphi code you can just refer to the returned XML as follows:

```
sXML := MyKamiakQryObject.FieldByName('XmlData').AsString();
```

Before doing this I was having a bear of a time with trying to extract the XML content of that query.

So I wanted to make sure to share this for the next guy.

Comment: This might mean something to you, but it is hard to see how this relates to the question given the minimal content of the question.

Comment: If I remember correctly... simply adding ", TYPE" on the end of the query smacked into errors when the kamiak component tried to execute the query. It worked fine in Query Analyzer though, so go figure.